# WPF Chart Binding doesn´t show any values

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I´ve got the following XAML-Code

```
<DVC:Chart Name="PieChart">
    <DVC:Chart.Series>
        <DVC:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding LoadPieChartData}" 
                       IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" 
                       DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
    </DVC:Chart.Series>
</DVC:Chart>
```

and in the code-behind file, I´ve the following:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,int>> LoadPieChartData
{
    get
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Item " + i, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Usually, the pie chart should show 20 values, but in my application it doesn´t show anything. 
When I set a breakpoint in the for-loop, it isn´t reached. 
Where is my problem?

EDIT:

I solved the problem by writing `this.DataContext = this` in the windows constructor!

Comment: Instead of using a key value pair maybe just throw together a class with a string and int value, create an ObservableCollection of this class and then try binding to that. Might help you figure out if the problem is the binding, or what you are binding to etc